# Access: Run multiple queries with a common variable

Tags: ms-access

So I have VB script that does many things.  First it has a input box that asks for an upload number that is manually entered.  That variable is used in a number of following queries in VB that delete and append other tables.  I created a macro to call that script but get the message that it can only be called 19 times.

If I were the one using this process, I'd just open up VB and run the macro manually but it needs to be used by other users.  What's the best way to handle running multiple queries automatically with a common input variable?

Comment: Why not call the VB code instead of calling the Macro. To an end user there isn't any difference.

Comment: I am not sure i follow your issue here. is your problem that you cant pass that input variable to other queries in a macro or you having trouble running multiple queries? as minty suggested, do all your stuff in vb, that will be easier and just have a single macro with one step that calls the vb function.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I figured out my issue.  I am able to keep all my queries in VB as is.  Realized that the project and script were the same name.  changed the name and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I find the best way to make variables widely accessible is to store them in a table.  Maybe use an update query to store your upload number in a table.  Use an append query if you want to keep a history of the upload numbers.